# What to do when a vow has been broken by a person?

Tags: belief

What to do when vow has been broken by a person? Can any prayaschit is there
What are the Prayaschitta measures for breaking a vow??? Here
Here the vow maker taken aperson(who took the vow) took it without knowing anything about it. Now
Now what kind of punishment(as per Scriptures) must the aspirantone undergo for the breakage ofbreaking such vow???
Here the vow maker took a vow to complete a vow when he gets job and in his mind he was thinking of a govt job but now he get a private job. Shall he have to fulfill his vow ??? Does his words taken into consideration or what he think will be taken into consideration???if he fulfill it now then it will be consider na that his vow is completed and when he get govt job then he don't have to do it again???

Comment: He can fulfill Vow now.

Comment: There are Prayaschits for every Karmas. You need not to be so afraid concerning it...

Comment: Can he fulfill vow before

Comment: Means if he said after this. Can he fulfill his vow before time if he know he can't fulfill it after he had said?

Comment: "took it without knowing anything about it"-What is meant by that?Do u mean he did not know about the significance of taking/fulfilling vow while he took it?

Comment: He took it in a Childish manner

Comment: As he said he will do this when he get admission in collage BT he didn't describe  the collage name and in his thought he was thinking of a collage name . so if he get admission in other collage in place of collage he has wish . shall he have to fulfill his vow??

Comment: @suman If that person fulfills his vow now even after getting admitted into other college, now God gets debt. So, God will definitely show his grace later.

Comment: And if god show his grace and he will get call from that collage which he wish will he have to do his vow again ?? As he did it before he don't have to do it again na.

Comment: @suman just mental thinking doesn't becomes Sankalpam for all... it's only for advanced Yogis who can fully control their mind who can take Mental Sankalpams...

Comment: OK so it means while taking a vow thinking will not be consider na only words will be taken into consideration?

Comment: Can you edit and replace '????????' with a single '?' .. I can assure you single '?' has the same effect :)

Answer (score 3):

Taking Vows and accomplishing them is related to personal belief. So, scriptures (Dharma Sastras) don't explicitly mention rules about "Vows".

This is what an Acharya from Telugu states [says](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xad_AuDgFAA) (Video in telugu)

> People take vows to fulfill their wishes or to get rid of their wordly
>   difficulties (*iShTa* or *kaShTa*). Now, arises the doubt of Sastra
>   Pramana for vows. For example, if a burglar takes a vow to not get
>   caught and police officer takes a vow to catch him and if both of them take vow to
>   same God, then which vow God should fulfill? So, it is purely
>   related to personal belief. It's always better to fulfill the vow in same temple, as this is related to belief.

This is what [Sri Annadanam Chidambarasastry](https://www.blogger.com/profile/11677443994890021401) [says](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DLoDwZ0kxIU&feature=youtu.be&t=90) (Video in telugu)

> Generally we feel there's no need to fulfill our vow if our problem is
>   not solved. But our conscience should agree with it. Lord knows what
>   is correct and not correct. For example, if we want to meet a person
>   for some urgent work and if we are waiting for a bus to go to his city
>   and bus got delayed, we ask God to send bus early and may take a vow
>   to visit temple if it fulfills. But we miss the bus and it turns out
>   the person whom we want to meet stays in the same city we live and we
>   saw him in Bus Station. Here, we didn't know what was correct but Lord
>   helped us. We may not get what we wish, but Lord grants the correct or beneficial thing to us. So, it's always better to fulfill our vow even though our particular wish is not fulfilled.

It's always better to fulfill our vow, irrespective of what we get. God owes us if we do that, as said by [Mylavarapu Srinivasa Rao](http://pedia.desibantu.com/mylavarapu-srinivasa-rao/) in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BzeDLgu_-XM) (Telugu). So, instead of Prayaschita, we can fulfill vow or from above statements, fulfilling vow can be considered as atonement.

Comment: So he can complete his vow now and he don't have to do it again na . completing his vow can be treated as his vow his completed and not broken??

Comment: @suman Yes. If he completes, there is nothing to do.

Comment: "It's always better to fulfill the vow in same temple, as this is related to belief." ... same temple? Why?

Comment: @sv. Because it's related to belief, not scriptures. If you have taken vow to visit Srisailam, it's better or suggested to go to Sriasailam, but not Rameswaram or Kasi, as your Antaratma believes that wrong thing happened as you didn't visit Srisailam. You can see 1st video.

Comment: As per the second video we should fulfil our vows made to God even if God doesnt fulfils our wish. Suppose a person made a vow to God's deity in a temple that if God heals his brother completely 100% then he will take his brother to Jagannath puri temple darshan.After some months, his brother healed but not 100% as he wished from God.Still he brought his brother to Jagannath puri darshan and completed his vow/promise which he made to God. Now after some more years,his brother got healed 100%.Do he has to bring his brother to jagannath puri darshan again and fulfil his vow again?

Answer (score 3):

Suppose, a person goes to a temple and makes the following promise in front of god - "If this particular wish of mine is fulfilled then I am going to do this in return", then once his wish really gets fulfilled he better fulfill the promise too. Because, otherwise it is considered as an offense.

> **Now if anybody makes a false promise** or swears falsely, taking the Tûlasî leaf in his hands, if
>   **anybody makes a false promise**, taking the Ganges water, S’âlagrâma stone, or any other images of God in his hand; if anybody swears
>   falsely, placing his right palm on the palm of another; if anybody
>   swears falsely, being in a temple or touching a Brâhmana or a cow; if
>   anybody acts against his friends or others, if he be treacherous or if
>   he gives a false evidence; **then all these persons go to Jvâlâ Mukha
>   hell**, and remain there for fourteen Indra’s life periods, chastised
>   and beaten by My messengers and feeling pain as if one’s body is being
>   burnt by red hot coal.
>
> **Devi Bhagavatam Book 9, Chapter 35**

(NOTE - This is only a partial answer as I have not given any praysachittas yet)